# Is there any way to run cloud-init on a Redhat 5 instance in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redhat, cloud-init

Redhat 6 includes cloud-init hooks, which means in AWS you can install cfn-init and use CloudFormation.

Redhat 5 doesn't appear to have cloud-init.  Is there any way to get this working?